# Understanding find command

Tags: linux, find

I am trying to find any file named lets say `dork`, but I want to exclude the files that are `dork.zip`. I'm also removing all the errors from permissions to directories.

So I have composed the command as such:

```
find /  -name "dork*" -and !"zip" 2>&1 | grep -iv "not"
```

This did not work as I expected.

Comment: Please explain how it is not working as you expect.

Comment: Sure. I have strategically placed files dork0.log dork1.log and dork3.zip in different directories.  Without the -and operator it finds all the files. but with the -and it bombs out.

Comment: ITYM `\! -name '*zip'`, not `!"zip"`.  BTW, `-and` is unnecessary - it's the default conjunction for `find`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
find / -name 'dork*' ! -name '*.zip'
```

You need to use two `-name` tests. One for matching `dork*` and one for matching `*.zip`.  The second of these should be inverted (the `!`) so that the found names do not match it.  There is always an implicit AND between the tests.

Making the implicit ANDs visible:

```sh
find / -name 'dork*' -a ! -name '*.zip'
```

Also using non-standard GNU syntax:

```sh
find / -name 'dork*' -and -not -name '*.zip'
```

To ignore errors produced by this, redirect the standard error stream to `/dev/null` with `2>/dev/null` at the end.

With GNU `find` you could instead choose to not enter directories that are not readable:

```sh
find / \( -type d -not -readable -prune \) -or \
       \( -name 'dork*' -not -name '*.zip' -print \)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I spent hours trying to figure this out and within 30 mins I have my answer.  Thank you and to everyone for monitoring and helping us newbs out!

Comment: Note that the last one would fail to report a `dork` file if it's a non-readable directory. You could still get errors if there are non-searchable directories (you may even get more errors as now `find` needs to lstat every file).

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the syntax for the `find` expression. I think you're expecting the `-name` test to treat `"dork*" -and !"zip"` as the pattern it looks for, but `-name` expects *a single pattern string*, not some sort of expression. The way `find` is parsing it is: (the name matches `dork*`) and (`!zip`), with `!zip` being a separate subexpression from the `-name` primary. But `!zip` isn't a valid expression, so you get an error.

You want something more like (the name matches `dork*`) and (the name does not match `*.zip`).

```
find /  -name "dork*" -and '!' -name "*.zip"
```

(The `-and` is not really needed; I left it in here for clarity.)

I've made a few other corrections here: The pattern is `*.zip`, because `zip` would only match a file named *exactly* "zip". The `!` is separated by a space so that `find` will recognize it as a separate element, rather than part of something else, and I single-quoted it so if you use the command interactively, the shell won't try to interpret it as a history reference.

BTW, what's going on with the `2>&1 and`grep -iv "not"`? If you're trying to filter error messages, and are using bash (not some other shell), you can use command substitution to avoid mixing the output and error streams:

```
find /  -name "dork*" -and '!' -name "*.zip" 2> >(grep -iv "not" >&2)
```

Comment: I was just trying to filter out stderr for things like this /Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Caches/CloudKit/com.apple.Safari: Operation not permitted
find: /Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari: Operation not permitted
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory

Comment: @ConfuseD Do you want to suppress errors entirely? If so, `2>/dev/null` will do the trick.

Comment: yes.  Thanks, that works slick!!